# Large Complex List Of Items In Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listitem

Take the following example screen:

[image: Sample screen with multiple complex items]

This screen is displaying all current offers, these offers are dynamic.

What would be the best way of implementing the 'Offer' item? Should I use a ListView with a custom ListItem or is there a better solution to handling a list of complex items like this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just create a xml with the layout you want like this one, and use it for each row.

Comment: You can use custom list view.You have to create custom xml layout to match with this UI components.Using list view may be easy for your other manipulation events like take out information related to offers.

Comment: Custom `ListView` with a lazyload for images is the best possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an adapter with a list that contains a cell layout.

```
public class ListObject {
    public int layout;
    ... other fields;
}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListObject>
```

and in the getview method, inflate the view that is needed for the offer.

```
public View getView(...) {
    ListObject lo = getItem(position);
    convertview = inflater.inflate(lo.layout, null);
}
```

is this what your trying to do? if not explain your question a bit more.